# How to left-align exercise questions (exercise package)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exercises

Given the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the output ("Exercise 1") left-aligned? I've tried everything I could think of, from `\flushleft` and `\raggedleft` (from the `ragged2e` package) to reading the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf) and trying to issue some `\renewcommand`s, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redefine `\ExerciseHeader`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{exercise}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{%
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{\large \ExerciseName\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle\ExerciseHeaderOrigin}%
  \par\nopagebreak\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Exercise}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I had to insert a space between `\ExerciseName` and `\ExerciseHeaderNB` so the exercise number isn't juxtaposed to its name, though. My document is much more legible now, thanks!